# JavaScript calendar not working when adding a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JS calendar script that works fine in one div. I also have a jQuery script that takes the div and clones it. The calendar script does not work in the cloned div, though. The calendar does not pop up. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#addRow').click(function () {
    $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'extraPerson',
        html: GetHtml()
    }).hide().appendTo('#container1').slideDown('slow');
});

function GetHtml() {
var len = $('.extraPerson').length;
var $html = $('.extraPersonTemplate').clone();
$html.find('[name=puloc]')[0].name = "puloc" + len;
$html.find('[name=pudate]')[0].name = "pudate" + len;
$html.find('[name=putime]')[0].name = "putime" + len;
$html.find('[name=punumber]')[0].name = "punumber" + len;
return $html.html();
}
});
</script>


<div class="extraPersonTemplate">

<table frame="box" style="width:500px">
      <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
  <?php
        //php code to access mysql database 

        echo '<select name="puloc" style="width: 482px">'; 
        echo '<option value="">--Select Origin Location--</option>'; 
        while($opt = mysql_fetch_array($resultOptions)) 
        { 
           echo '<option value="'.$opt['displayName'].'">'.$opt['displayName'].'</option>'; 
        } 
        echo '</select>'; 
     ?>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script> 
   Pick up date:<BR>
   <input class="tcal" placeholder="" type ="text" name="pudate" style="width:130px">
</td>
<td>
   Pick up time<br>
   <input placeholder="" type ="text" name="putime" style="width:150px">
</td>
<td>
   Pick up number<BR>
   <input placeholder="" type ="text" name="punumber" style="width:150px">
</td>
</tr>
</table>



<div></div>
</div>


<div id="container1">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script> 
</div>
<a href="#" id="addRow"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> Add Origin</p></a>
```

Here is my javascript file on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/WEhJHUKe

Comment: Why do you include tcal.js three times? And are you including jQuery?

Comment: Have to `re init` your calender after the clone. From the looks of it you that is done by calling `f_tcalInit()`

Comment: ie - the calender script does not 'watch' for newly created `.tcal` elements ( nor should it really )

Comment: How would I go about implementing this? Sorry, I'm new to JavaScript and am more used to html and php. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The tCal code only runs once, when you generate the page (see the very final method in the js class, which adds an event handler for window.onload). It looks at the page at that time and adds the tCal element to the row it sees with the class 'tcal'. Adding another row (even with that class) will not trigger another update.

When you add another row, try running f_tCalInit() again--this should force it to inspect the page again, find your new row with the 'tcal' class, and append the date control to it.

Comment: I've tried both of these below, and neither is working. Am I doing something wrong?

1. adding f_tcalInit() in getHtml() function
2. adding f_tcalInit() in my container1 div

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that binds the calendar into a function, and after cloning and adding a new field to page, call the function again to bind the calendar again